# Echo Username After Login

Tags: php

I have created a login and a main page, id like to echo my username after I Login. I'm not sure what to fix, or what to add.

Below is my code:

Login.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
require_once './config/config.php';
//If User has already logged in, redirect to dashboard page.
if (isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in']) && $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] === TRUE) {
     $_SESSION['first_name'] = $_POST['first_name'];
    header('Location:index.php');
}

//If user has previously selected "remember me option", his credentials are stored in cookies.
if(isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password']))
{
 //Get user credentials from cookies.
 $username = filter_var($_COOKIE['username']);
 $passwd = filter_var($_COOKIE['password']);
 $db->where ("user_name", $username);
 $db->where ("passwd", $passwd);
    $row = $db->get('admin_accounts');

    if ($db->count >= 1) 
    {
     //Allow user to login.
        $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['admin_type'] = $row[0]['admin_type'];
        header('Location:index.php');
        exit;
    }
    else //Username Or password might be changed. Unset cookie
    {
        unset($_COOKIE['username']);
        unset($_COOKIE['password']);
        setcookie('username', null, -1, '/');
        setcookie('password', null, -1, '/');
        header('Location:login.php');
        exit;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-EN">
        <h1>Login</h1>

<div class="work n5">

 <div id="login">

  <p style="font-size:130%;"><strong>Welcome.</strong> Please login.</p>

  <form method="POST" action="authenticate.php">

   <fieldset style="border:none;">

    <p><input type="text" name="username" required="required" required value="Username" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Username'" onFocus="if(this.value=='Username')this.value='' "></p> 

    <p><input type="password" name="passwd" required="required" required value="Password" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Password'" onFocus="if(this.value=='Password')this.value='' "></p> 

    <p><a onclick="toggleModal()">Forgot Password?</a></p>
                 <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_failure'])){ ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in">
     <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
     <?php echo $_SESSION['login_failure']; unset($_SESSION['login_failure']);?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <p><input type="submit" style="font:inherit; font-size:13px;" value="Login"></p>

   </fieldset>

  </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Index.php (Page After Login)

```html
<?php
session_start();
require_once './config/config.php';
require_once 'includes/auth_validate.php';

//Get DB instance. function is defined in config.php
$db = getDbInstance();

//Get Dashboard information
$numCustomers = $db->getValue ("customers", "count(*)");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-EN">
    
                    <div class="infoWrapper">
                        <div class="title">
                            <span>Welcome Back</span>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="counter">
                            <span> <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name'];?>  - Tech</span>
                        </div>
```

authenticate.php

```html
<?php 
require_once './config/config.php';
session_start();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
{
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
    $passwd = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'passwd');
    $remember = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'remember');
    $passwd=  md5($passwd);
    
    //Get DB instance. function is defined in config.php
    $db = getDbInstance();

    $db->where ("user_name", $username);
    $db->where ("passwd", $passwd);
    $row = $db->get('admin_accounts');
     
    if ($db->count >= 1) {
        $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['admin_type'] = $row[0]['admin_type'];
        if($remember)
        {
         setcookie('username',$username , time() + (86400 * 90), "/");
         setcookie('password',$passwd , time() + (86400 * 90), "/");
        }
        header('Location:index.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['login_failure'] = "Invalid username or password";
        header('Location:login.php');
        exit;
    }
  
}
```

Comment: After `header(..)` redirect..... `exit()` should be called so no other codes will be executed after redirect.

Comment: Post code of `authenticate.php`.

Comment: I just did that, nothing really changed :(

Comment: Mr. Blue just posted authenticate.php :)

Comment: authenticate.php - Inside `if ($db->count >= 1) {..}`  - add line - `$_SESSION['user_name'] = $username;`

Comment: Same file - move `session_start();` before `require_once`

Comment: I love you <3 Thank you so much it worked

Comment: Do you know how i could echo first and last name?

Comment: On the index.php it gives my username

Comment: i wanted to know if it was possible to output first_name and last_name

Comment: authenticate.php - after `$row = $db->get('admin_accounts');` - add - `var_dump($row);` - what's the output?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Nothing, im not sure what var_dumb($row); did

Comment: How? Could you please explain? to echo first_name and last_name

Comment: Try: https://pastebin.com/qvVKudnV - output pls?

Comment: I just did that, it took me to authenticate.php instead of index.php and it gave me an array of all the user information including first and last name. How do i echo that in index.php

Comment: Can you post the output here? You can remove the password element if it's needed.

Comment: or pastebin it.

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> int(12) ["user_name"]=> string(6) "admin" ["passwd"]=> string(32) "" ["admin_type"]=> string(5) "super" ["position"]=> string(5) "Other" ["first_name"]=> string(6) "James" ["last_name"]=> string(14) "Mo" } }

Comment: To set session value for first_name and last_name - https://pastebin.com/dhFrZaUn

Comment: To show first name and last name in `index.php` - you can use variables -  `$_SESSION['first_name']` and `$_SESSION['last_name']`

Comment: IT WORKED! YOU ARE AMAZING! Thank you sooo much